# python tkinter entry widget input host&port won't connect(socket.connect) to server

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm testing a simple chat server&client. When I wrote in bash/terminal the client connects successfully to server but when I implement the tkinter GUI(trying to make it more like an app...) meaning adding entry widget to put in host and port, it will never establish connection with the server, Im really desperate and have no hack of what's wrong with it. 
Please kindly review my code below and point out my mistake thanks. my code is written in python3.

Here is the client code(where my problem is):

```
from tkinter import *
import socket, sys, select
INPUT_HOST = ''
INPUT_PORT = ''
# Client is where the problem exists

class CONNECTION():
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.s.settimeout(2)
        try:
            self.s.connect((INPUT_HOST,int(INPUT_PORT)))
        except:
            print('Unable to connect.')
        e3.bind("<Return>",self.enter_pressed)
    def enter_pressed(self,event): #<---simple function I can send messages to server.
        input_get=e3.get()
        self.s.send(input_get.encode())
        print('>:', input_get)
        e3.delete(0,'end')

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack(side=TOP,fill=X)

def click_connect():
    INPUT_HOST=e1.get() #<---------here I pass the entry to INPUT_HOST
    INPUT_PORT=e2.get() #----------so the socket can use to establish
    print(e1.get(),e2.get()) #-----connection.
    conn = CONNECTION(root)
def click_connect_2(): #<----------this a backup test in whcih I can
    conn = CONNECTION(root) #------hand type host&port from bash
l1=Label(frame,text="Host:")
l2=Label(frame,text="Port:")
l1.grid(row=0)
l2.grid(row=1)
e1=Entry(frame) #<------------------here i enter host from GUI
e2=Entry(frame) #<------------------here I enter port from GUI
e1.grid(row=0,column=1)
e2.grid(row=1,column=1)
b1=Button(frame,text='connect',command=click_connect)
b1.grid(row=3,column=0)

e3=Entry(root)
e3.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
INPUT_HOST=input('enter host:\n')
INPUT_PORT=input('enter port:\n')
b2=Button(frame,text='connect bash',command=click_connect_2)
b2.grid(row=3,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

below is the server code(no problem) for you to copy/paste to tryout:

```
import socket
import select
import sys, time

'''server NO problem the problem is on client '''
SOCKET_LIST = []
HOST = ''
PORT = 9009
RECV_BUFFER = 4096

def chat_server():
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
    server_socket.bind((HOST,PORT))
    server_socket.listen(10)

    SOCKET_LIST.append(server_socket)

    print("chat server started on port %s"% PORT)

    while True:
        ready_read, ready_write, in_error = select.select(SOCKET_LIST,[],[],0)

        for sock in ready_read:
            if sock == server_socket:
                conn, addr = server_socket.accept()
                SOCKET_LIST.append(conn)
                print("Client: %s is connected."% str(addr))
            else:
                try:
                    data = sock.recv(RECV_BUFFER).decode()

                    if data:
                        print("%s\n%s: %s"% (time.ctime(),str(addr),data))
                        if data == 'socket list':
                            print("socket_list:"+ i for i in SOCKET_LIST)
                    else:
                        if sock in SOCKET_LIST:
                            print("%s: disconnected."% str(addr))
                            SOCKET_LIST.remove(sock)
                except:
                    print("%s: disconnected."% str(addr))
                    continue
    server_socket.close()


if __name__=="__main__":
    sys.exit(chat_server())
```

Comment: In `click_connect()`, you are assigning to *local variables* `INPUT_HOST` and `INPUT_PORT`, that are entirely unrelated to the global variables of the same names that you are using elsewhere.

Comment: Oh m god You have sharp eyes, I can't believe I miss such small things. You a life savior you just freed me from a two days headache thank you so much I declared global in the method and it works.!!!  I declare the question solved.